# Развертывание приложения на Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Web-приложение развернуто на Tomcat. Проблема такова у некоторого количества пользователей плохой интернет, томкат сбрасывает соединение у таких пользователей. Приложение написано на java. Вопрос такой, что делать? Нужно решить данную проблему, но я не понимаю куда копать. Искать настройки томкат? Обрабатывать самим приложением?

Answer (score 2):

В настройках Tomcat вы можете сконфигурировать TCP-соединения. Например поменять свойство `keepAliveTimeout`:

> Количество миллисекунд, которое этот Connector будет ожидать другого
>   HTTP-запроса до закрытия соединения. Значением по умолчанию является
>   использование значения, которое было установлено для атрибута
>   `connectionTimeout`. Используйте значение `-1` для указания отсутствия
>   (т.е. бесконечного) тайм-аута.

---

Можно также посмотреть другие свойства соединения, полный перечень можно найти [здесь](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html).